# Get data of many relations | Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i have 3 model, Client, Payment and Transactions.

```
Client has_many payments
Payments has_many  transactions
```

I want to know how to get the `client.transaction`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :payments      
  has_many :transactions, through: :payments
end

Client.first.transactions
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this :

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :payments
    has_many :transactions, through: :payments, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Now you can get all transactions of the first users with `Client.first.transactions`.